# Is it possible to set multiple default values for a checkbox?

Tags: wss-3.0

We have a days of the week working pattern that the user can select any of Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu and Fri from, so the list has a Choice with multiple values allowed.

Ok can set the default value to Mon and SharePoint is happy, but is it possible to set it to multiple values?

I looked at manually created items and the field was showing ...

```
;#Mon;#Tue;#Wed;#Thu;#Fri;#
;#Wed;#Thu;#Fri;#
;#Mon;#Wed;#Thu;#
;#Mon;#Tue;#Wed;#Thu;#Fri;#
```

But tried those as defaults and SharePoint objected  :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to List Settings
2. Edit your field
3. Change the "Default value:" radio button to be "Calculated Value"
4. Enter a formula like: `=";#Mon;#Wed;#Thu;#"`

Answer (score 0):

In SP 2013, you have to do it in this way

=";#My Anniversary;#" & ";#Project documentation;#"

Comment: the `&` is just concatenating the strings -- the string you're setting is equivalent to `=";#My Anniversary;#;#Project documentation;#"`. -- I was able to get it to work without the ampersand, and without doubling the `;#` field separators between my values in SharePoint 2013.